# Dozer-Mapping.xml: Cannot find the declaration of element 'mappings'

Tags: xml, spring, web-services, dozer

I am trying to implement Dozer mapper in my Spring Web Service Project.
I am getting below error:
**EXCEPTION:**

org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [dozer-mapping.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [projectName/application-context.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 4 in XML document from class path resource [folderName/dozer-mapping.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'mappings'.
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 4 in XML document from class path resource [employeeelectionrs/dozer-mapping.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'mappings'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)

**My Code:**
Dozer-mapping.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mappings xmlns:ns="http://dozer.sourceforge.net"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://dozer.sourceforge.net
http://dozer.sourceforge.net/schema/beanmapping.xsd">
 <mapping>
<class-a>org.testing.ui.types.HistoryRequest</class-a>
<class-b>org.testing.api.types.HistoryReq</class-b>
<field>
    <a>Status</a>
    <b>StatusCode</b>
</field>
</mapping>
</mappings>
```

**application-context.xml**

```
<import resource="dozer-mapping.xml"/>  
<bean id="dozerBeanMapper" class="org.dozer.spring.DozerBeanMapper">
    <property name="mappingFiles">
        <list>
            <value>dozer-mapping.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Dozer Jars Used:
- commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
- commons-lang-2.6.jar
- dozer-5.3.2.jar
- jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar
- log4j-1.2.15.jar
- slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar
- slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar

I have got above jars from the Dozer official web page.
I have tried  n number of times but whenever  i am starting my **Weblogic** server, the above said exception is been thrown.
Kindly help/guide.

Comment: Why are you importing the dozer-mapping.xml inside your spring configuration?! It should only be loaded by the DozerBeanmapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the line with `<import resource .. />`. Why should the mapping configuration be loaded as part of the spring configuration file. The only bean interested in this configuration should be the `DozerbeanMapper`.

```
<bean id="dozerBeanMapper" class="org.dozer.spring.DozerBeanMapper">
    <property name="mappingFiles">
        <list>
            <value>dozer-mapping.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: @ Deinum As you said  i removed <import resource .. /> from spring context xml.
It worked and server started with no errors.But in my java file  i am calling the bean **dozerBeanMapper** . 
The code is    
destinationOBj = dozerBeanMapper.map(sourceObj, DestinationClass.class);    
When control comes over here, again i am getting same exception ........ 
org.xml.sax.SAXException: Parsing Error
Line:    4
URI:     null
Message: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'mappings'.&#xD;

Comment: I am doing mistake some where but not able to find it up.. Kindly guide me out of this

Comment: dozer-mapping.xml--- <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mappings xmlns:ns="http://dozer.sourceforge.net"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://dozer.sourceforge.net  http://dozer.sourceforge.net/schema/beanmapping.xsd">

 <mapping>
 <class-a>org.package.esb.ClassA</class-a>
 <class-b>org.package.esb.ClassB</class-b>
 <field>
  <a>status</a>
  <b>statusCode</b>
 </field>
 </mapping>
</mappings>

Comment: Please post the full stack trace in your initial question.